# How to make django association reference to itself

Tags: django, django-models

I have:

```
class Direction(models.Model):
    left = models.OneToOneField(
        'self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='right')
    right = models.OneToOneField(
        'self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='left')
```

The error:

> ant.Direction.left: (fields.E302) Reverse accessor for 'ant.Direction.left' clashes with field name 'ant.Direction.right'.
> HINT: Rename field 'ant.Direction.right', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'ant.Direction.left'.

How does one make this relationship so that `a.left = b` and `b.right = a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use as `related_name` the same as the fields that have been defined. You likely do not want to work with two `OneToOneField`s anyway, you can define a single `OneToOneField`, and set the related name to the opposite, so:

```
class Direction(models.Model):
    left = models.OneToOneField(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='right'
    )
    # no right
```

So now if a direction *a* has as `.left` a direction *b*, then *b* has as `.right` the object `a`.

If there is no `.right`, then accessing `.right` will raise a `Direction.DoesNotExist` exception, we can however fix this issue by making use of another for the `related_name`, and work with a property that will wrap it in a `try`-`except`:

```
class Direction(models.Model):
    left = models.OneToOneField(
        'self',
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name='_right'
    )
    
    @property
    def right(self):
        try:
            return self._right
        except Direction.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    @right.setter
    def _set_right(self, value):
        self._right = value
```

Comment: Will b.right then return Null or raise notfound?

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie: raise a not found, but you can override that behavior with a simple trick.

Comment: @Tjorriemorrie: see update. Here we work with a related name that is `_right`, and we write a getter and setter as something in between that will return `None` if right is not available, and assign to `self._right` if necessary.